# Selenium 4 Edge/Chrome Webdriver not working in C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I have Edge version 107.0.1418.26 and Egde web driver version 107.0.1418.26 (chrome also has the correct versions). Selenium webdriver 4.5.1.

I had everything working a few weeks ago using chrome, I have revisited the project recently and everything has stopped working (reason for also trying Edge).

To restart at the basics I'm using the Microsoft example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp and Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

When I run:

```
    var driver = new EdgeDriver();
    try
      {
      driver.Url = "https://bing.com";
      ...
```

The webdriver console opens and initially says 'started successfully' but the c# code times out on the first line stating 'cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:55553'. I get a little more information with the Chrome test.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54097/devtools/browser/8e320eae-3f01-4ae2-9944-414ca8ad36e1
[23128:31564:1101/105231.394:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [10:52:31.393] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

I don't know why it is trying bluetooth!

Initially I thought the problem to be a security issue over a remote desktop connection but I'm now in the office with the same issue. Something is niggling towards security but I can't find any further information or logs.

********** UPDATE *********

After vs2022 update, Java update and 4 reboots it now works again.

Can anyone come up with any reasons why it would just stop and cause the above problems? (the drivers were not left running in background). I'm very nervous to continue if I can't understand why errors are caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No true answer, however complete reboot (cold restart) then ensuring everythign os on the latest version worksfollowed by another reboot works evey time.